# Why does Excel not recognize related tables when connecting to PostgreSQL via ODBC?

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerbi, odbc

When I connect to PostgreSQL via ODBC, Excel doesn't see any related tables while there is. What is interesting, Native PostgreSQL connector in Power BI sees all related tables.

I know the issue is with ODBC, is there any workaround for Excel so that I won't have to manually choose related tables and then recreate relationships between them in Power Pivot?

Answer (score 1):

The native Postgres connector should be also available in Excel (PowerQuery):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/postgresql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/#p

Comment: The thing is it is not available in Excel 365, only in Power BI

Comment: Did you follow up in the referred links?  There is section about prerequisites and a driver so-called NpgSQL. Good luck!